# mySQL between dates that span over multiple years

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-format, between

Hi I was wondering why this statement is working in mySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`myTable`) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creationDateTime, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '02/21/2011' AND '03/20/2011'
```

but this is not

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`myTable`) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creationDateTime, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '12/21/2010' AND '03/20/2011'
```

The first statement returns 'xx' count of the number of rows while the second one returns '0'

The only difference I see is that the "from" date is in 2010 and the "end" date is in 2011. To test if this was the problem I queried from '12/31/2010' and it still gave me 0 results but when I set the start date as '01/01/2011' it gave me the number of records that were created in that time span.

Is there something I am missing with regards to mySQL's BETWEEN and using dates from different years?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT() returns a string, not a date.  By using it you're forcing a string comparison instead of a date comparison.  You should omit the DATE_FORMAT and use YYYY-MM-DD date strings instead.

Comment: Got it. The only reason I used DATE_FORMAT was because if I specify my end date as '2011-03-20' it does not pick up records that were created on the 20th of March.

Comment: Are the fields you're working with DATETIME ot TIMESTAMP fields?  Because if they are then the time will be taken into account for the comparison.  Midnight on 2011-03-20 will be in range, but any time after that won't be.  You can use DATE() to work with just the date parts of timestamps and datetimes, this should make items created on your end-date be included in the range.  WHERE DATE(creationDateTime) BETWEEN '2010-12-21' AND '2011-03-20'

Comment: Yeah should have thought of that. I ended up inserting a 00:00:00 to the "startDate" and 23:59:59 to the end date. That kind of works too, but I prefer just using the DATE function. Will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the date format `BETWEEN '2010-12-21' AND '2011-03-20'`.  Also remove the DATE_FORMAT() function.

So, this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE creationDateTime BETWEEN '2010-12-21' AND '2011-03-20'
```

Comment: The DATE_FORMAT function bit is fine, it doesn't mess with the dates.

Comment: The DATE_FORMAT function is going to cause a string comparison and you'll end up comparing months to years.